# Problems with toString() and Overriding Methods

Tags: java, overriding, tostring

I am having a problem with this code.  It is not calculating area correctly.  I need it to calculate the cross-sectional area of a Cylinder/Piston and the surface area of the cylinder.  If you notice the output it seems that both values are the same values for when I use the getArea() method.  Java is getter confused as to what getArea() to use?  strong text  I am trying to over-ride the getArea() [Surface Area] with getArea() [cross -sectional area] but it is not working?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(
        "\n\nInput the radius, then the height, then if the cylinder is filled (input 1 if it is filled and input 0 if not, and then enter the color");

    double radius = scan.nextDouble();
    double height = scan.nextDouble();
    int filled = scan.nextInt();

    boolean isFilled;
    if (filled == 1) {
      isFilled = true;
    } else {
      isFilled = false;
    }

    String c = scan.nextLine();
    String x = scan.nextLine();

    Cylinder cyl = new Cylinder(radius, height, isFilled, x);
    System.out.println("\n\n This is a Cylinder and its properties");
    System.out.println(cyl);

    Piston small= new Piston();
    System.out.println ("\n\n This is small Piston");
    System.out.println(small);

    Piston big = new Piston(55.6, 1234.4, true, "red", 1200, 12.3);
    System.out.println ("\n\n This is big Piston");
    System.out.println(big);
  }
}

class Shape {
  private String color = "yellow";
  private boolean filled;

  public Shape() {

  }

  public Shape(String color, boolean filled) {

    this.color = color;
    this.filled = filled;
  }

  public String getColor() {
    return color;
  }

  public void setColor(String color) {
    this.color = color;
  }

  public boolean isFilled() {
    return filled;
  }

  public void setFilled(boolean filled) {
    this.filled = filled;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return "\nThe color is : " + color + " and shape fill is : " + filled;

  }

}

class Cylinder extends Shape {
  private double cylinderRadius;
  private double cylinderHieght;

  public Cylinder() {
    cylinderHieght = 10;
    cylinderRadius = 2.5;
  }

  public Cylinder(double height, double radius) {
    cylinderRadius = radius;
    cylinderHieght = height;
  }

  public Cylinder(double height, double radius, boolean filled, String color) {
    super(color, filled);
    cylinderRadius = radius;
    cylinderHieght = height;
  }

  public double getRadius() {
    return cylinderRadius;
  }

  public double getHieght() {
    return cylinderHieght;
  }

  public double getArea() {
    double p = 3.14;
    return 2 * p * cylinderRadius * cylinderRadius + 2 * p * cylinderRadius * cylinderHieght;
  }

  public double getVolume() {
    double p = 3.14;
    return p * cylinderRadius * cylinderRadius * cylinderHieght;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + " \nRadius= " + cylinderRadius + " Height= " + cylinderHieght
        + " Cylinder total surface Area= " + getArea() + " volume= " + this.getVolume() + ".";
  }
}

class Piston extends Cylinder{
  private double shaftLength;
  private double myPressure;

  public Piston(){
    shaftLength=1;
    myPressure=1;
  }
  public Piston(double height, double radius, boolean filled, String color, double length, double pressure){
    super(height, radius, filled, color);
    shaftLength=length;
    myPressure=pressure;
  }
  public double getShaftLength(){
    return shaftLength;
  }
  public double getPressure(){
    return myPressure;
  }
  @Override
  public double getArea(){
    return getRadius()*getRadius()*3.14;
  }
  public double getVolume(){
    return super.getVolume();
  }
 @Override
  public String toString(){
    return super.toString()+"\n the cross sectional area of Piston = "+this.getArea()+" shaftlength="+shaftLength+" pressure="+myPressure+" .";
  }
}
```

Here is the output if I put in a radius of 5 and a height of 10.

> Input the radius, then the height, then if the cylinder is filled
>   (input 1 if it is filled and input 0 if not, and then enter the color
>   5 10 1 Blue
>
> This is a Cylinder and its properties
>
> The color is : Blue and shape fill is : true Radius= 10.0 Height= 5.0
>   Cylinder total surface Area= 942.0 volume= 1570.0.
>
> This is small Piston
>
> The color is : yellow and shape fill is : false Radius= 2.5 Height=
>   10.0 Cylinder **total surface Area= 19.625** volume= 196.25.  t**he cross sectional area of Piston = 19.625** shaftlength=1.0 pressure=1.0 .
>
> This is big Piston
>
> The color is : red and shape fill is : true Radius= 1234.4 Height=
>   55.6 **Cylinder total surface Area= 4784554.150400002** volume= 2.6602121076224005E8.  **the cross sectional area of Piston = 4784554.150400002** shaftlength=1200.0 pressure=12.3 .

Comment: Please add the Java tag.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify -- it seems like this is the situation:

1. You have one class (`Cylider`) that defines a method (`getArea()`) to do one thing. Another method on `Cylider` (`toString()`) calls that `getArea()` method.
2. Then, you sub-classed `Chylidar` with a child type (`Piston`) and overrode the `getArea()` function to do a different thing.
3. Now, when you're code in the `Cylider` class clls the `getArea()` method, you expected it to use the `Cylider` version of `getArea()` **because the code was written in the same class**, but in reality it used the overriden `Piston` version of `getArea()` **because the object you were calling it on *actually was a Piston***.

This isn't really a bug or even a problem to solve -- it's just a function of how Java resolves method calls. It will pick the one that is *most specific* given the actual type of the object you are working with (even if it's not obvious at compile time what that type would be) *not* the one that is written closest to the sight of the caller.

There isn't really a way to get around this. I would take this as a sign that your design is bad -- or at least not idiomatic. Overriding functions is intended for you to give a different, more correct way to calculate the *same idea* for a *different type*, not just as a way to re-use function names.

The easiest change would probably be to just make a new method on `Cylinder` called `getCylinderArea()`. `Cylider.getArea()` could call this function by default, but you could call it explicity in `Cylider.toString()` if you wanted that function to only ever use the plain Cylinder method of calculating area.

Alternatively, Maybe Piston shouldn't actually be a subtype of `Cylinder` because, even though they share some characteristics, a Piston isn't substitute-able for a generic cylinder anywhere you would use a cylinder -- for example, when calculating the area. Look up the [Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for more.

Personally, though, I tend to stay away from inheritance altogether for this exact kind of reason. I would actually recommend just using interfaces and a flat hierarchy in this case instead.

[This StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262693/how-to-ignore-bypass-an-overridden-method) might be interesting if you want more detail on calling super methods.